# CSS Zoom effect on load - hide DIV/Image loading latency

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a web site with a lot of images, I already have lazy-loading but I wish to add some
effects when the images loads

I was looking to reproduce the "zoom" effect when the image is "loading", something like here:
https://masonry.desandro.com/

Please, have a look at this one:
https://tympanus.net/Development/GridLoadingEffects/index8.html

You will notice that there is no effect when the image are already loaded.
I try to hide the 'load latency' when loading an image from the server.
Maybe the animation is not the right trick!

The goal is to have the load softer, now it loads like any image, but the effect is not very nice.
(you can check [www.socloze.com](http://www.socloze.com) for review).

Do you think we can do this in pure CSS (without JS)?

Comment: please add a minimal reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example your website isn't accesable without giving your location

Comment: Probably not without some JS as pure CSS does not have some 'onscroll' trigger.

Answer (score 1):

You can add initial animation:

```css
.img-anim {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url('https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/Dv3m6UV5rC0KL0or-iOT-6i1I4i4I3CXNh-XU0WZ5-yG_vbYme6A8NhIasiwLon0td1DGbVFBDOEwi3LK7gegowFkjQEiJpPBg');
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  animation-name: scale-in;
  animation-duration: .4s;
}

@keyframes scale-in {
  0% {
    background-size: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    background-size: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="img-anim"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have edit my question! Because I try to load the "image loading" latency, ie. when the image is not yet loaded from the server... how can we hide the ugly HTML re-rendering effect with something nice :-( ?

Answer (score 1):

You can create initial animation usings css but thats as far as u go, if you need things to pop up as you scroll down then check [AOS](https://michalsnik.github.io/aos/)